# Pull to refresh

Tags: objective-c, ios5, pull-to-refresh

My code always works with an 'standerd' UITableview, but now i implanted a Tableview in a viewcontroller. My code is not working (pull to refresh) does anyone know why?

In a normal UITableview it works but hmm, maybe i'm missing some stuf because it's a tableview in a ViewController.

i'm using; https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh

```
- (void)reloadTableViewDataSource{

    //  should be calling your tableviews data source model to reload
    //  put here just for demo
    _reloading = YES;

}

- (void)doneLoadingTableViewData{

    //  model should call this when its done loading
    _reloading = NO;
    [_refreshHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDataSourceDidFinishedLoading:self.tableView];

}
```

I used NSlog and it's calling both function's but it not showing the blue 'pull to refresh' bar and it also do not scrolls up after loading.

Comment: Are you actually adding it to the tableView?

Comment: @Paul.s it's a uitableview in a viewcontroller!

Comment: I mean did you actually add the pullToRefreshView to the tableView

Comment: How do you mean? i downloaded it and implanted it.. @Paul.s

Comment: Show the code where you alloc/init the pullToRefreshView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer below links for the same.

https://github.com/shiki/STableViewController

https://github.com/vincentmac/PullToRefresh

https://github.com/thermogl/PullToRefreshTransform

https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh

https://github.com/pothibo/PHRefreshTriggerView

Answer (score 0):

Why not moving to a already coded, stable and well known and external code?
Have a look at [EGOTableViewPullRefresh](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh).

it might solve your issue.

Comment: i'm using it but it does not work, please check my first message.